# Keyboard Shortcut for Home Folder broken

Tags: settings

In System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Applications, I like to bind 'Home Folder' to:
`super + E`
and I bind Terminal to:
`super + T`

Now both keybindings just open a terminal.

I tried changing the 'Home Folder' keybind to a couple other combinations. These other combinations just didn't work (did nothing at all).

I changed it back to:
`super + E`
afterwards and it's opening a terminal again.

I use the same keybinding settings on my other PC (eOS) and they are still working fine.

Comment: Test the  screenshot shortcuts. My shortcuts break with every boot recently. I've filed a bug and am still trying to figure out what's causing it. I've talked with others who have also noticed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that my default File Browser, under System Settings -> Applications, was set to Terminal. I don't remember changing this setting, but changing it back to Elementary's 'Files' definitely fixed my problem.

Now, I am embarrassed.